aws sdk go secretsmanager list with filters V1 and V2
How can I properly apply the filters in the function ListSecrets
v1 example
func GetSecretManagerList(svc secretsmanageriface.SecretsManagerAPI) (*secretsmanager.ListSecretsOutput, error) {
    var value []*string
    value = append(value, aws.String("mtls"))

    filters := &secretsmanager.Filter{
        Key:    aws.String("name"),
        Values: value,
    }

    input := &secretsmanager.ListSecretsInput{
        MaxResults: aws.Int64(2),
        Filters:    filters,
    }

    result, err := svc.ListSecrets(input)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return result, nil
}

v2 example
func GetSecretManagerList(ctx context.Context, client secretsmanager.Client) (*secretsmanager.ListSecretsOutput, error) {
    filters := []types.Filter{{Key: types.FilterNameStringTypeDescription, Values: []string{"mtls"}}}

    result, err := client.ListSecrets(ctx, &secretsmanager.ListSecretsInput{
        MaxResults: aws.Int32(2),
        Filters:    filters,
    })

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return result, nil
}

In both cases I tested connected directly to AWS, or using the unit test and mocking, the ListSecretOutput and the filter do not work.

When you say that the filter do not work I take that the you get no matches in the result.
I can't tell why the filter is not matching exactly since I don't know the names of the secrets that you are matching against.
But do note that Filter requires name to be a prefix match and it is case sensitive.
